# Ivar showing null although it's strongly referenced and initialized and allocated

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have class called A with a public ivar called lines of type NSMutableArray. I allocate and initialize the ivar in the init method. On the other hand I have another class called B which has a strong reference to an ivar of type class A. I allocate and initialize the class A in the init method of class B. What I would expect:

The public ivar of the class A should not be null after the the class B has allocated and initialized the class A as its instance variable. What I get:

When I do the following I find the lines variable of the class A variable to be null:

```
   myClassAVariable=[[ClassA alloc]init ];
   NSLog(@"The lines object is %@",[myClassAVariable lines]);
```

Note: I'm using cocos2d.

EDIT:

Here's the part of the ClassA.h file;

```
@interface ClassA : CCLayer 
{
    NSMutableArray *lines;
}
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *lines;
```

Here's the part of the init method of the ClassA:

```
if( (self=[super init]) ) {
   lines=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return self;
```

Here's the part of the interface of the ClassB:

```
 @interface ClassB : CCLayer
 {
       DrawLayer *draw;
 }
 @property(strong,nonatomic)DrawLayer* draw;
```

And finally, here's the init of the ClassB:

```
if( (self=[super init]) ) {
   draw=[[DrawLayer alloc] init];
        CCLOG(@"Lines object is %@",[draw lines]);//Shows "Lines object is (null)"
}
return self;
```

Comment: Can you show us the init of ClassA

Comment: `myClassAVariable=[[ClassA alloc]]init ]` is invalid syntax, could you post the actual code?

Comment: Ho do you know it's strongly referenced? can you paste the definition of `ClassA` ?

Comment: Have a look at my answer below, you need to invoke the setter by `self.lines`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `lines` is just an ivar, that would not invoke its setter when calling `[[ClassA alloc]init ];`. I would suggest making it a strong property:

ClassA.h:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *lines;
```

in ClassA init method:

```
//initiliaze lines:
self.lines = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: It did actually work, man. I had forgotten just another little nuance. I forgot that I had to call self.draw.lines instead of [self.draw lines]. :) So thanks for reminding.